# is it possible to add custom httpheader filed in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-ee-6

is it possible to add custom httpheader filed in spring boot in resttemplate

I have tried add/set but in server side  nit able to retried the keyvalue @requestHeader.  How to get the values inserver side?

```
 httpHeaders.set("keyvalue","keyvalue");
   httpHeaders.add("keyvalue","keyvalue");
```

Comment: I didn't get it. Do you want to add a custom HTTP header for a request that originated in your application? Or you want to check if a header exists when you receive a request?
For either there are ways.

Comment: i want add keyvalue in header . (not with default customer field)

Comment: Can you provide the actual code you are running?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, but it is a bit of misuse of the headers. If you are trying to pass some key-value properties that are relevant for your particular server and the task that your REST API performs, then it looks like you want to send it as a parameter within your request body or in the URL in case of GET method. With URL it might look like:
[HTTP://myserver:8080/myservice?key1=value1&key2=value2](http://HTTP://myserver:8080/myservice?key1=value1&key2=value2). And in your controller you may have something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/myservice")
public MyServiceReturnDTO myService(@RequestParam Map<String, String> queryParams) {
...
}
```

your queryParams map will contain the map `{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}`

Comment: the requirement is passing in header only. its some sensitive data. so dont want to pass in request body or query param

Comment: If it is sensitive data, than passing it in URL is not acceptable, body or header the security should be on the same level.

Comment: Yes that i understand. but to pass it in header

Comment: I didn't work with RestTemplate class. I use an Http client that I wrote myself and it is part of an Open Source Library. In my client, you can set any header you wish. On your server-side, I assume you can retrieve it. If you want you can try it. Here is the link to Javadoc: http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html, See method setRequestProperty(java.lang.String propertyName, java.lang.String value) for setting a request header.

Comment: You can get the library as maven artifact here: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils or on Github (including source code and Javadoc) here: https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases

Comment: its going to server and giving error like Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level

Comment: So, your server method doesn't expect your custom header. Just as I suggested, you need to use POST method and pass your sensitive info in the request body and not as a custom header. both headers and body pass as part of the body in HTTP request. So it is the same security. You can check it by reading contents of your HTTP request as a stream. You will see that it contains both headers and body.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add headers from the request then i think you can use `HttpHeaders` like this

```
@GetMapping("/get")
public ResponseEntity<String> getAllReturnedObjectType() {
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.set("key","value");
...
return new ResponseEntity.Ok()
.headers(responseHeaders)
.body(objectType.getAll());
```

Comment: the same way i used it . but I name it as httpHeaders